# How do I select several keys from tarantool at once, like with SELECT IN in SQL?

Tags: tarantool

I want to select several records from Tarantool in one call, but don't see how can I pass several keys to `space:get` or `space:select`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more variant equivalent to the SQL query `select * from "test" where "id" in (1, 3)` using [LuaFun](https://luafun.github.io/):

```
tarantool> box.space.test:pairs():filter(function (tuple) return tuple.id == 1 or tuple.id == 3 end):totable()
```

It is a generic variant if there is no 'id' index in the space, and it implies performing fullscan.

If a unique index named "id" exists, a more efficient variant is possible:

```
tarantool> fun.iter({1, 3}):map(function (value) return box.space.test.id:get(value) end):totable()
```

Otherwise if the index is not unique, then it will look like

```
tarantool> fun.iter({1, 3}):map(function (value) return box.space.test.id:select(value) end):reduce(function (result, data) for _, rec in ipairs(data) do table.insert(result, rec) end return result end, {})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using Lua as well as SQL.

1) Use a stored procedure in Lua, like this one:

```
function select_several(space_name, index_name, keys)
    local obj = index_name == nil and box.space[space_name] or box.space[space_name].index[index_name]
    local result = {}
    for _, key in pairs(keys) do
        table.insert(result, obj:get(key))
    end
    return result
end
...
select_several('test', nil, {1, 2})
```

2) Starting with Tarantool 2.0, you can use SQL (provided that you have space format):

```
box.execute('select * from "test" where "id" in (1, 3);')
```

Comment: Please help. How can I escape strings?
box.execute('select * from "test" where "id" in ('1', '3'test');') - returns error

I use golang tarantool.client.Eval()

Comment: It can be done like this box.execute([[select * from "test" where "id" in (?,?);]], {"1'1", "3"})